# Match for any text into search box

Tags: spring, spring-boot, specifications

I use this Search specification to try to search text by title. It's working fine if I type the exact search String:

```
public Page<ClassCategoriesFullDTO> findClasses(ClassCategoriesSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<Product> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (params.getTitle() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("title"), params.getTitle()));
            }
            if (params.getType() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), params.getType()));
            }
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
        return classCategoriesService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(classCategoriesMapper::toFullDTO);
    }
```

How I can modify the code to search into DB with every text I type into DB table?

Comment: Can you make an example how do you want to search?

Comment: maybe you want smth like this?
`cb.like(
  cb.lower(root.get("title")),
  cb.lower(params.getTitle())
)`

Comment: yes, for lower case it should work. But if I type "na" how to make a query for all names which include "surname"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the criteria builder's (cb) like a method to search for "an" to get "surname"

```
static Specification<ClassCategoriesFullDTO> titleContains(String title) {
    return (root, cq, cb) -> cb.like(root.get("title"), "%" + title + "%");
}
```

If you want to ignore the case then use:

```
static Specification<ClassCategoriesFullDTO> titleContains(String title) {
    return (root, cq, cb) -> cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("title")), "%" + title.toLowerCase() + "%");
}
```